# Single quote problem in sqlite on android. Need to solve without replacing quotes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery

            ("SELECT * FROM table where word like '?%'".replace("?", 
              letter),null);
```

When there is a single quote in string `letter` app crashes.
Need to solve without `letter.replace(" ' ", " ")` because there are words in table with quotes in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the statement API incorrectly.  You should bind the literal string value you want to appear in the actual query.  That is, do this:

```
String param = letter + "%";
String query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE word LIKE ?";
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, new String[] { param });
```

It is the API's responsibility to correctly escape the `LIKE` expression you are trying to build.